# matlab how is it possible to curve fitting Fourier series to more than 8 part ?

Tags: matlab, fft, curve-fitting

how is it possible to curve fitting Fourier series to  more than 8  series part ?

i try this programmatic but i get not the same coefficient value  and the fitting is not good

```
    %% Create a Fourier series

    AnCosWnx='A0';
    BnSinWnx='';
    lower=1;
    upper=1;
    startpoint=0;

  for n=1:9



   LCos=AnCosWnx;
   LSin=BnSinWnx;

   ACosWx=strcat('A',num2str(n),'*cos(w*',num2str(n),'*x)');
   AnCosWnx=strcat(LCos,'+',ACosWx);
   BSinWx=strcat('B',num2str(n),'*sin(w*',num2str(n),'*x)');
   BnSinWnx=strcat(LSin,'+',BSinWx);

   Fx=strcat(AnCosWnx,BnSinWnx);


  end

  %% build the fit  function 

   options = fitoptions(Fx);


   lower=zeros(1,2+n*2);
   upper=zeros(1,2+n*2);
   startpoint=zeros(1,2+n*2);

  lower(1:end)=-inf;
   upper(1:end)=inf;
  startpoint(end)=6.17*10^-3;

set(options,'Lower',lower,...
   'Upper',upper...
   ,'StartPoint',startpoint...
   ,'Algorithm','Trust-Region');
```

%%

```
 ft = fittype(Fx);


% Fit this model using new data
[fitobject ,gof,output] = fit(sat,dat,ft,options);
```

%% create the fit function to string

```
    cvalues = coeffvalues(fitobject);
    cnames = coeffnames(fitobject);
    output = formula(fitobject);

  for ii=1:1:numel(cvalues)
      cname = cnames{ii};
      cvalue = num2str(cvalues(ii));
      output = strrep(output, cname , cvalue);
 end
```

%%  convert the output string to function
       Foutput= strcat('@(x)',output);

```
  Fout=  regexprep(Foutput,'\r\n|\n|\r','')
   g=str2func(Fout);
   hold on 
   h_ = plot(sat,g(sat),'r')
```

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the matlab (or any) curve fitting algorithm generally won't work very well above a certain complexity of function. You could use piecewise splines but it seems that a [periodogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-squares_spectral_analysis) might be the best solution. This is a technique to fit a Fourier series to non-uniform data. There is a matlab function on the [exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20004-lomb--lomb-scargle--periodogram).